# could not establish connection to "<host name>"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, remote-server

I am not able to connect with aws ec2 instance in vs code through remote ssh from my home wifi.
But when I try connect with mobile net then it connects with ec2 instance.

Below is what I am getting while connecting from my wifi.

```
[10:53:20.718] Log Level: 2
[10:53:20.722] remote-ssh@0.92.0
[10:53:20.722] win32 x64
[10:53:20.728] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+test-crilic", attempt 1
[10:53:20.728] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[10:53:20.728] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[10:53:20.729] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"crilc_vikralya":"linux","crilc_bob":"linux","test_ec2":"linux","test-crilic":"linux"}
[10:53:20.729] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[10:53:20.729] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[10:53:20.729] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[10:53:20.729] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[10:53:20.729] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[10:53:20.729] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[10:53:20.730] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[10:53:20.730] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[10:53:20.730] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[10:53:20.730] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[10:53:20.730] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[10:53:20.730] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[10:53:20.730] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[10:53:20.734] SSH Resolver called for host: test-crilic
[10:53:20.734] Setting up SSH remote "test-crilic"
[10:53:20.741] Using commit id "6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b" and quality "stable" for server
[10:53:20.745] Install and start server if needed
[10:53:20.749] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[10:53:20.793] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, Libr
[10:53:20.794] > eSSL 3.4.3

[10:53:20.799] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 53829 "test-crilic" bash
[10:53:20.802] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:53:42.844] > ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:53:42.845] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[10:53:44.137] "install" terminal command done
[10:53:44.138] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:53:44.138] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:53:44.140] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[10:53:44.142] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\Lenovo\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js:1:583821)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Lenovo\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js:1:582473)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\Lenovo\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js:1:679811)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async c:\Users\Lenovo\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js:1:642614
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Lenovo\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js:1:645932)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\Lenovo\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js:1:643664)
    at async c:\Users\Lenovo\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js:1:722342
[10:53:44.153] ------
```

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the instance? Is it limiting Inbound access to a specific IP address?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No it's not limiting inbound access to a specific ip address , I have opened it all for ip's  i.e, 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Have you compared the output of the one that works with the one that fails, to find the first difference in the log?